Apply NSG to incoming traffic from site-to-site VPN
In azure, when a site-to-site VPN is created, a virtual network gateway-specific subnet is added to be associated to this gateway. Supposing I would like to apply NSG rules to incoming traffic (like I don't control the other side of the VPN), should I apply the network rules in the NSG belonging to the gateway's subnet?
I could add NSG rules in each specific subnet but my line of thinking was to block all traffic unless specifically allowed, since it's external.
If that doesn't solve the problem or is not a good solution, what's an alternative solution?

If you do not control the other side of the VPN, then you should place a firewall at your side to filter the traffic from the other side, no different than connecting your network to the public Internet. You did not vet the people on the other side of the link, so you do not trust them with your network.

I definitely thought of that, the problem being the cost associated with the firewall. Just out of curiosity why an NSG in the gateway subnet is not a suited solution?
